# How to make sense of `f(array[i], i, array)` found in `d3.min()` source code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I am new to d3 and try to learn it by reading its source code. I start with probably the simplest function [`d3.min()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-array/blob/master/src/min.js). However, my hair was torn apart by a seemingly very common code `f(array[i], i, array)`.

1. I think `f()` is supposed to be a function;
2. `array[i]` is accessing the element of `array` at index `i`;
3. `i` is an index of the `array`;
4. `array` is an array of numbers given by user.

If the above 4 understandings are correct, then `f()` as a function given by the user, must have all three of `array[i]`, `i`, `array` as its arguments. But we don't have to use all of these arguments, right?

What is the point of this `f()`? Can anyone offer any useful example/usage of `d3.min(array, f)` in which `f` is not `null`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Thanks @NiettheDarkAbsol, this link is very helpful.

Comment: yes your points are correct. And no you don't have to pass all the arguments. However if you only pass two the first two arguments will be populated where as the others will not. But if you pass say, f(val,val, null, val) that could be a way to pass what ever arguments you wish. The whole point of f can't be known here as we don't know what f is but basically it's a function that should use the arguments passed to it

Comment: Personally, I think your approach to learning D3 will be rather cumbersome. If you want to learn more about it's workings, have a look at the article [*D3.js Source Code Walkthrough Part 1*](http://prajitr.github.io/d3-source-walkthrough-pt1/) which gives you a head start by taking a top-down perspective instead of your bottom-up approach. Unfortunately, despite its title I am not aware of any Part 2 of this article. Keep in mind, though, as mentioned in the article, that it is essential to first get a good grasp of the D3 way by going through some tutorials.

Comment: Actually, you can be an excellent dataviz coder and make a very good use of D3 with never looking at the source code.

Comment: And, as a word of caution, the article linked to in my previous comment covers D3 v3. With v4 on the horizon many things will change, but I still think it is well worth reading.

Comment: Thanks @altocumulus, the article looks very interesting. I will take a good look at it. The reason why I felt a bottom-up approach may be the only way for me to move forward at this moment is that being a newbie in javascript and d3 I may understand ok but not at all confident that I got a good grasp of the usage of d3 functions by reading many of the beginner d3 examples. In fact I tried to read doc and dissect beginner examples for my own uses, but I found doc is still too abstract without small examples, and difficult to dissect and digest without understanding each function well.

Comment: Thanks @GerardoFurtado, I would very much appreciate your approach on how to become an excellent dataviz coder without reading source code. Could you tell me more?

Comment: IMO, you have to know how to use D3 functionalities to be a good dataviz coder, not knowing *how* those functionalities work under the hood (or bonnet). Allow me to make a comparison with Formula 1: to be a champion you have to know how to drive, not how a power unit, a transmission or a differential works (it's a plus, though)

Comment: In a nutshell: knowing *how to use* D3 is not the same of knowing *how D3 works* internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little confusion here. First, `d3.min` and `d3.max` can be used with or without an accessor. In the API:

> d3.min(array[, accessor])

This square bracket before the comma means that it is optional, not compulsory. So, you can have a simple:

```
var something = d3.max(someArray);
```

Or, using an accessor (as you asked, an example where the accessor is not `null`):

```
var something = d3.max(data, function(d) {
    return d.foo
});
```

Now we come to your question: you can see in the code above that the accessor function has only 1 argument.

The example you provided is the source code D3 uses to deal with the accessor function. If you look at the code, you'll see `array[i]`, `i` and `array`. Those 3 arguments are not provided by the user, but passed to the accessor function  by the D3 source code.

Remember that in JS you can pass more arguments than parameters or less arguments than parameters.

Comment: Actually, the accessor function can have up to three arguments being the current element, the index and the array itself. This is what the source snippet does: calling the accessor `f` with the current element `array[i]` at index `i` and provide the `array` itself. However, you are right that it's up to you what you make out of that by specifying the  parameters accordingly. @Kenny

Comment: Thanks, altocumulus. I made a small edition to make clear that these arguments are passed to the accessor by the source code itself.

Comment: To be even more specific you could change your second snippet to using `d3.max(data, function(current, index, array) {`.

Answer (score 0):

The f is a callback function. We use callbacks all the time in JavaScript. So this function works the same way as the map or forEach method does on standard Arrays. It also has the same call signature of value, index and array.

```
d3.min([1,2,3], (v,i,arr)=>10-v ) // 7
d3.min([1,2,3]) //1
```

When we call the min function with a 'callback' like the above the answer is the third item in that array but gives the answer as 7 (because 10 - 3 is 7)

Comment: `d3.array.min` will give you `Uncaught TypeError`. Use `d3.min` instead.

Answer (score -1):

adding a `f` function to find the minimum value of the array while this minimum value being `>= 6`

```js
     var array = [10, 2, 3, 4, 5];
      // find the minimum while >= 6
      var f = function(x, y, z) {
          if (x >= 6) {
              return x;
          }
      }
      var min = d3.min(array, f);
        
      console.log(min);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How is this an answer to the question? This is a follow-up at most.

Comment: Thanks @altocumulus, all the questions have been well answered by previous answers above, here I just want to share another `f` function example which  offers a meaningful condition on `d3.array.min`, given that I did ask for examples.